# Java: Function overloading

Tags: java, arraylist, types, overloading

Let's say we have two **functions**:

```
    public static void function1(ArrayList<Datatype1> dat1){
      doSomething();
    }

    public static void function2(ArrayList<Datatype2> dat2){
      doSomething();
    }
```

These two **functions do the same thing** but they take an ArrayList storing **different datatypes** as a parameter. Lets say **Datatype2 and Datatype1 are subclasses from the same superclass**.

Question:

How can I use **OOP** to write one function?

Comment: Do you want `function(ArrayList<? extends SuperType>)`?

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Ive been looking for this answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function(ArrayList<? extends SuperType>)
```

answered by Louis Wasserman solved my problem. I post this to check this answer to be solved.